# What might cause my Sony Tablet S to run very slowly

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, stock-android

My Sony Tablet S has developed a gross speed problem. For the last several months it has run exceedingly slowly most of the time.  Apps take 10's of seconds to start, taps to bring up menus take similar times, and more often than not I get a "Application is not responding" snag message to which I have to answer "Wait' to get the menu to drop down.  I sometimes get spontaneous reboots when opening an app.

I used a Task Manager called Free Advanced Task Manager which shows the CPU usage.It varies from 15% to 117%.  When It was indicating 117% there was no individual task with any appreciable CPU usage.

The tablet is not rooted, Android v 4.0.3 5a.  Some apps on SD card, card (32g) is about half filled.  Device memory has around 1G spare.  RAM usage is usually about 300/750 Mb.

My question is: what are the likely causes for this and how do I track down the offender?

Comment: The first thing I would recommend is installing Watch Dog so it can utilise watching your CPU usage. Secondly just do an install of something like All-In-One Toolbox, and performing relevant tasks; clear cache, delete temp files and more importantly disable services and apps on startup. Would you be able to provide screenshots of your CPU usage etc.? I'd classify this as a good start!

Comment: Why install more and more apps? Backup all your data and make a factor reset.

Comment: @DavidBaumann I considered this, and that may well be what I will do eventually, but it will obliterate any hope of knowing why this has happened, and I'l like to know why.

Comment: So you must check any APP that you installed. Also check the systems log files, the file system, CPU and GPU Temperaturen, storage wear...